# Trying to specify a value in a 2d NSMutableArray of known size?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to set a value in a 2d array of known size:

trying this but it fails:

```
[[ppp objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:3] = @"dog";
```

or

```
[[ppp insertObject: @"dog" AtIndex:1] AtIndex:3];  //<<-- still doesn't like
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-objectAtIndex:` does return a value, but nothing you can assign to (i.e. not an lvalue). Instead use [`-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABBBECB).

```
[[ppp objectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:@"dog"];
```